# Why would stored proc query results be sorted differently in SSMS vs SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, sorting, stored-procedures, reporting-services, bids

I have a stored proc that takes in parameters and returns a result set, with sorting defined by an order by statement within the proc's query.

When I execute the proc in SSMS, the results are returned in the order desired.

When I execute the proc in BIDS' query editor window, the results are sorted in an unknown order.

There are no additional order by statements or sorts applied, and this is the results in the query editor, not after a tablix sort has been applied (either way, there aren't any sorts on the tablix).

Does anyone know a reason why this would be, or have any suggestion for what stupid thing I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add the `ORDER BY` to the SP **after** defining the data set in BIDS?

Comment: I don't believe so, but would that imply something?

Comment: I've had issues where changes in the SP didn't come over to the data set unless I refreshed the data set.  In some weird cases I've had to remove and re-add the data set.

Comment: Just for fun I went ahead and deleted and rebuilt the data set, the issue remains

Comment: If you watch the query being called by BIDS in Profiler, does the order by statement look correct?

Comment: As far as I can see in profiler, there are just calls to the procs, which contain the order bys, with no differences

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59675/discussion-between-dave-gugg-and-kscott).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we can't explain what exactly was causing the problem, but after an un-related reboot of the SQL Server serving the data to the report server, the sorting is now working correctly. I assume something was cached somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Per MSDN, data is displayed in the order it is received. Apparently this can not be trusted. I suggest explicitly setting the sort on the list or tablix.